# bsddb.btopen alternative on Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

So I have my Notebook on Google Colab using Python 3 (and I will implement some Deep learning libraries ex: Keras, TF, Flair, OpenAI...) so I really want to keep using Python 3 and not switch to 2.

However, I have a .db file that I want to open/read, the script is written in Python 2 because they are using **bsddb** library (which is deprecated and doesn't work on Python 3)

```
self.term_to_id = bsddb.btopen(resource_prefix + '_term_to_id.db', 'r')
```

I tried modifying the Python 2 file to make it compatible on Python 3 so I can import it as a module in my Google Colab Notebook, what I tried:

1. I tried changing bsdbb to bsdbb3, and installing `!pip install berkeleydb` so I can do that later `!pip install bsddb3` and just update **bsdbb** to **bsdbb3** , but upon installing `!pip install berkeleydb`I get the following errors:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> berkeleydb (from versions: 18.1.0, 18.1.1, 18.1.2, 18.1.3, 18.1.4)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for berkeleydb

2)I thought maybe I could just import the dependency from python 2 file to my Python 3 notebook, but as expected it didn't work because it didn't recognize `'import bsdbb'` in the Python 2 file.

Any tips/ work around to make it work on Google Colab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`berkeleydb` is only Python binding on database `BerkeleyDB` created in `C/C++`.

When I try to install it on my local system Linux Mint then I see error with

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'src/Modules/berkeleydb.h'
```

which means that it tries to compile some `C/C++` code.

And this usually need to install special package with `C/C++` headers (files `.h`) with suffix `-dev`.

Using

```
!apt search Berkelay
```

I found that there is installed `libdb5.3` so I installed `libdb5.3-dev`

```
!apt install libdb5.3-dev
```

and after that Python can install `berkeleydb`

---

This works for me on `Colab`

```
!apt install libdb5.3-dev

!pip install berkeleydb

import berkeleydb as bsddb
```

Comment: Thank you so much